# Valgrind not working on 32-bit binaries

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, valgrind

I am using valgrind on my RHEL 64bit machine. However it refuses to run for 32-bit executables.

```
valgrind: failed to start tool 'memcheck' for platform 'x86-linux': No such file or directory
```

Does anybody know how to solve it? I can't change the binary to 64-bit as it has a large code associated with it.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you might need to get the source for [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) and build it for yourself.  The version you're trying to use appears to have been built for 64-bit only.

Comment: have you tried to install glibc-debuginfo for x86?

Comment: `it refuses to run for 32-bit executables`...maybe it's not the supplied executables, it's the `memcheck` binary itself is 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set VALGRIND_LIB to the corect path:

   export VALGRIND_LIB="/usr/lib/valgrind"
2. Valgrind needs to be compiled for the corect toolchain. (cross-compile) or install a valgrind 32bit package provided by your distribution.

Have a look here: [Bug 179472](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=179472)